# How can i do that with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just start learning javascript yesterday, because i'm really needing a code that does the following example: (I figured only the logic)

Two elements:

```
<div class="item bw" style="background-position: -10px -330px">
<div class="item bw" style="background-position: -10px -390px">
```

**Javascript** - detected "bw" class presence automatically (without any manual trigger)

**Javascript** - get `background-position %y` value and stores into a variable called `old-y`

**Javascript** - remove the `px` string that follows the number (-330px becomes -330)

**Javascript** - Does  `new-y = (old-y - 300) + "px"` (The Y will aways be negative, so to add a value we need to subtract more)

**Javascript** - Set the new background-position to the element

Done!

```
<div class="item bw" style="background-position: -10px -630px">
<div class="item bw" style="background-position: -10px -690px">
```

Sorry for anything. I just wanted to clear what i need.

---

I got this to working using this code:

```
window.onload = function() 
{
        var bws = document.querySelectorAll(".bw");
        for (var i = bws.length-1; i >= 0; i-- )
        {
            var ypos, pos;
            pos = bws[i].style.backgroundPosition.split(' ');
            ypos = pos[1].match(/(-\d+)px$/);
            bws[i].style.backgroundPosition = pos[0] + " " + (parseInt(ypos[1])-370)+"px";
        }
};
```

It was based on Niet the Dark Absol answer

Comment: When do you want these things to happen? Do you want to change the bg-position when the bw class is set on the element?

Comment: You want do do X, and you think you can solve it by doing Y, so you ask about Y, which is a strange thing to do. Just ask about X! What are you *really* trying to do? What should the end result be?

Comment: @Tibos I think I was clear

This occur when page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why yes you can, especially since the inital value is defined in the `style` attribute - that makes it a lot easier than if it were in a CSS file.

```
var bws = document.querySelectorAll(".bw"),
    l = bws.length, i, pos, match;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    pos = bws[i].style.backgroundPosition || bws[i].style.backgroundPositionY;
    match = pos.match(/(-\d+)px$/);
    if( match) {
        bws[i].style.backgroundPositionY = (match[1]-300)+"px";
    }
}
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok, for this I will need the entire dom structure of your HTML page. But I will try to answer logically. (Hoping that I understood your question correctly)

1) Lets say we write a function startOnLoad(){}
2) Call this function in the body tag with event onLoad = "startLoading()"
3) Give and id to you <body> tag
4) Use var Parent = document.getElementById(<bodytagId>)
5) After this depending on the structure of the HTML dom parsing.

parentNode
childNodes
firstChild
lastChild
nextSibling
previousSibling

like Parent.nextSibling will give the next node.
eg: temp = Parent.nextSibling;
    temp.id will return the id of the node. Store the value of id and do string comparison of 'btw'
6) if true, node use the following
Object.style.backgroundPosition to get or to set.
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use jquery

```
$('.item.bw').css('background-position', newValue);
```

or only the Y value

```
$('.item.bw').css('background-position-y', newValue);
```

Comment: Do you *see* a jQuery tag?

Comment: why the -2, this is the code to change the position

Comment: Yeah, IN JQUERY, which was NOT included in the question.

Comment: jquery is JAVASCRIPT or is this a complete different language Niels?

Comment: jQuery is not **native** to the browser though. [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is so amazing, that it comes standard.

Comment: Vanilla JS, intresting, will have a look at it.

Comment: @lordkain Niet is somewhat trolling you. vanilla is a term used to describe plain JS, with no libraries, frameworks, etc. If you hover over the javascript tag on SO you will see this: "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected." That is why your answer is downvoted.